# Prove logistic loss is convex and lipshitz

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to prove that $F(y,y_{pred})=\log(1+e^{-y\cdot y_{pred}})$ is convex while I know that $f(x)=\log(1+e^{-x})$ is convex because $f''(x)>0$, but I cant find a way to apply it on the multivariate case.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: $y\in\{+1,-1\}, y_{pred}\in R$

Comment: What is your domain? (for instance $x\mapsto \log(1-e^{-x})$ is convex for $x>0$, but not for $x<0$ ).

Comment: @OliverDiaz I updated the question

Comment: I am so sorry I did a mistake the real expression is (,)=log(1+−⋅) with "+" sign not "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ can only take two values, this is equivalent to just checking two single variable functions for convexity. Call $y_{pred} = x$.

If $y = 1$,

$F(1,x) = f_1(x) = \log(1+\exp(-x))$

If $y = -1$,

$F(-1,x) = f_{-1}(x) = \log(1+\exp(x))$

Since $f_1$ and $f_{-1}$ are both convex (check their second derivatives on their respective domains), $F$ is also convex.

Comment: Thank you!! but I am so sorry I did a mistake the real expression is (,)=log(1+−⋅)  with + sign not -

Comment: No worries, the result is still the same here.